# c++ const error

Tags: c++, constants

```
    bool check_integrity( int pos ) const
    {
        if (( pos <= 0 ) || ( pos > max_seq ) || ( pos  >= _length + _beg_pos ))
        {
             cerr << "!! invalid position: " << pos
                  << " Cannot honor request\n";
             return false;
        }

        if ( _isa == ns_unset ) 
        {
             cerr << "!! object is not set to a sequence."
                  << " Please set_sequence() and try again!\n";
             return false;
        }

        if ( pos > _elem->size()){
             cout << "check_integrity: calculating "
                  << pos - _elem->size() << " additional elements\n";
             ( this->*_pmf )( pos );
        }

        return true;
    }


    public:
        typedef void (num_sequence::*PtrType)( int );
    private:
        PtrType    _pmf;
```

> The above code clip is part of class "num_sequence". I got an error for the
>   following line:

```
( this->*_pmf )( pos );
```

> The error is: 'const num_sequence *const this' Error: the object has
>   type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a non-const member function pointed by `_pmf` for a constant object `*this`. This is a violation of const-correctness rules.

Either declare your `PtrType` as

```
typedef void (num_sequence::*PtrType)( int ) const;
```

or remove `const` from your `check_integrity` function

```
bool check_integrity( int pos )
{
   ...
```

Either this or that. You didn't provide enough information for someone else to decide which is the right thing to do in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`check_integrity` is a `const` function so functions it calls must also be `const`, hence to call a `PtrType` function is must also be `const`.

Try this:

```
typedef void (num_sequence::*PtrType)( int ) const;
```

NB: I didn't compile this :) Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
typedef void (num_sequence::*PtrType)( int );
```

to

```
typedef void (num_sequence::*PtrType)( int ) const;
```

since you are calling the function from a `const` function